# No data when retrieving NSManagedObject by ID and assigning to property

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am attempting to move all of my edit operations in to their own `NSManagedObjectContext`s so that any background save operations can continue without accidentally committing unfinished changes. Only on confirmation do I save the changes into the parent context.

After creating my temporary context, I have to locate the 'real' object in that context -

```
Item *tempItem = (Item *)[temporaryContext objectWithID:[realItem objectID]];
```

Logging confirms that the correct `Item` object is located and the `tempItem.name` is correct. So I go ahead and use the `tempItem` as follows:

```
[editItemViewController setItem:tempItem];
```

However, when I try to access the `tempItem` property within `EditItemViewController`, data for the object is a fault:

```
<Item: 0xc249720> (entity: Item; id: 0xc39cab0 <x-coredata://BBAD105F-EA03-4593-885A-26C2FA5468AD/Item/p11> ; data: <fault>)
```

For example, attempting to log `editItemViewController.item.name` logs `null`.

Why is the data a fault when accessing it as a property of the view controller, when it wasn't  at the time I retrieved it?

Comment: Was the importing context (`temporaryContext`) deallocated/released?

Comment: I don't think so - I'm using arc

Comment: Try importing the object you need by its `objectID` in your view controller and see if this makes a difference. If you are releasing your temporary context before using the item, the item will be un-faulted.

Comment: It does make a difference. Why would the context be released when the object is not?

Comment: I don't know the entire scope of your implementation so it is hard to say. But, by the name of the context, it's life span is probably the function it is declared in, after that your fetched objects are orphaned.

Comment: "Fault" is a normal part of Core Data and is not en error on its own. Have you tried looking up any of the attribute values on the object?

Comment: Yes - the name, as per the last part of the question. I thought that looking up the name should 'fill in' the data but it is not behaving that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep `temporaryContext` as a strong property in your `editItemViewController`